# Problemas con JOIN en Mysql

Tags: mysql, join, inner

Estructura del registro de entradas

[image: Estructura Entrada]

Estructura del registro de salidas

[image: Estructura Salida]

tengo la siguiente consulta en Mysql

```
SELECT camaras_log_entradas.matricula, camaras_log_entradas.hora_entrada, camaras_log_salidas.hora_salida FROM `camaras_log_entradas` INNER JOIN camaras_log_salidas ON camaras_log_salidas.matricula = camaras_log_entradas.matricula
```

Me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: resultados del sql]

Como se ve en la imagen tengo un coche que ha entrado y salido 4 veces, como puedo hacer para que no me lo repita como lo hace sino que me devuelva la primera salida con la primera entrada y asi sucesivamente las 4.

Tengo que tener las 4 entradas y las 4 salidas, no puedo guardar la ultima salida

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora con la estructura de tablas queda más claro, gracias.

Si el valor `codigo_entrada` de `camaras_log_entradas` coincide con el de `camaras_log_salidas`, solo tendrías que agregarlos al `JOIN` (he puestos alias a las tablas para que sea más fácil de leer):

```
SELECT 
    ce.matricula, 
    ce.hora_entrada, 
    cs.hora_salida 
FROM 
    camaras_log_entradas ce
        INNER JOIN camaras_log_salidas cs
            ON cs.matricula = ce.matricula
            AND cs.codigo_entrada = ce.codigo_entrada
```

La cosa es que el SQL necesita de algo para relacionar los datos ¿Cómo sabe el SQL que la primera entrada va con la primera, la segunda con la segunda y así? Recuerda que los datos en una tabla no están ordenados y, aunque lo estuvieran, tienes que indicarle qué va con qué.

Intenta no hacer `DISTINCT` solo esperando que arroje el resultado que esperas. Eso son apaños que a largo plazo terminan en dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Jose Constenla, así es como se soluciona, con el único problema, que ese campo ahora esta vacío en ambos, pero cuando termine el desarrollo lo implementare para que funcione y así quede todo como debe ser. Nuevamente muchas gracias

Comment: @elyera Encantado de ayudar! Si lo logras implementar y te parece la solución correcta, por favor selecciónala como tal =)